# In Dragon Age 2, can I safely sell all junk?

Tags: dragon-age-2

In Dragon Age 2, can I sell all items labeled "Junk" without having to fear I would need any of this later? (for quests/crafting/etc)

Vials of Darkspawn Blood for example were a quest item in Dragon Age: Origins, I think, and are labeled junk in DA2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes: junk is just that. You can safely sell it all.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Whats the point of the "Stash all junk" button in your storage crate then? Sounds pointless if you are always better of just selling it.

Comment: @atticae Some junk might have sentimental value to you? :) I think it's just a hold-over from *Dragon Age: Origins* where you got to choose what you considered junk, so there was some value to stashing it just in case you wanted to free up your inventory right away but give your junk selection a once-over later before selling it.

Comment: You can make any item junk. So I could see stashing all junk if it is mostly weapons and armor. Still kinda odd though.

Comment: Don't forget if you sell it there is a 'Buy Back' tab :)